# Problemas em projeto Java com CDI (Weld) + Hibernate + PrimeFaces

Tags: java, primefaces, hibernate, cdi

boa noite.
Estou com problemas para executar meu projeto com a estrutura descrita no título dessa postagem.
Estou usando Hibernate, com controle de transações pelo servidor (JTA).
Segue as classes de meu projeto.

Bean que é referenciado na página xhtml:

```
    @Named
    @RequestScoped
    public class EmpresaBean implements Serializable {

        @Inject
        private EmpresaDao teste;
        private Empresa empresa;

        public EmpresaBean() {
        }

        public void gravar() {
            try {
                teste.create(getEmpresa());
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

        public Empresa getEmpresa() {
            return empresa;
        }

        public void setEmpresa(Empresa empresa) {
            this.empresa = empresa;
        }

    }
```

DAO:

```
    @Stateless
    public class EmpresaDao {

        @PersistenceContext(unitName = "testePU")
        private EntityManager em;

        public EmpresaDao() {
        }

        public void create(Empresa entity) {
            em.persist(entity);
        }

    }
```

Persistence.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
      <persistence-unit name="testePU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <description>Forge Persistence Unit</description>
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>TesteDataSource</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
          <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
          <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
          <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
          <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion" value="true"/>
          <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
        </properties>
      </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

Ao mandar executar estou recebendo este erro, segue o log:

```
    Grave:   Exception during lifecycle processing
    java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: org.jboss.jandex.ClassInfo.hasNoArgsConstructor()Z
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:168)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    Grave:   Exception while loading the app
    Grave:   Undeployment failed for context /Teste
    Advertência:   AS-CDI-00036
    Grave:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: org.jboss.jandex.ClassInfo.hasNoArgsConstructor()Z
```

Desde já agradeço quem puder me ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Tá faltando uma *lib* no seu projeto. Se for um projeto Maven, adicione a seguinte dependência:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
    <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Victor, estou usando Maven. Adicionei a dependência que você falou mas continua do mesmo jeito. Primeiro é lançado um NullPointerException em seguida java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.jandex.ClassInfo.hasNoArgsConstructor()Z
 at org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.jandex.JandexClassFileInfo.

Comment: Fiz uma alteração, estava faltando o Listener do Weld no Web.xml, acrescentei e agora o erro mudou:
    Grave:   Exception while loading the app :     java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:     org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager

Comment: mande o stacktrace do novo erro e verifique se estais importando as anotações compatíveis com as tuas dependências.